# log4net watch does not reload configuration

Tags: log4net

I am trying to write an application that changes the logging level when config file is changed.

```cs
class Program
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(@"log4net.config"));

        do
        {
            log.Debug("Hello World!");
            log.Info("I'm a simple log4net tutorial.");
            log.Warn("... better be careful ...");
            log.Error("ruh-roh: an error occurred");
            log.Fatal("OMG we're dooooooomed!");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        } while (true);
     }
```

My config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\log-file.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="FATAL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

As far as I understand (correct me if I am wrong), the watch part means that the XML configuration is reloaded on change of the file. I try to change the debug level, while the program is running, but the level is changed only if I restart the program.

I've tried using `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "Log4Net.config", Watch = true)]` in AssemblyInfo instead of configuring in main, with the same problem, changes are not watched.
I would appreciate any insights.
Tal

Comment: I would post what your config looks like and how you are changing it as well as verifying that you are changing the right config file (changing it in debug directory vs root project directory).

Comment: Any luck getting the watcher working?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get your logger from your logmanager:

```cs
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(@"log4net.config"));

    do
    {
        ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
        log.Debug("Hello World!");
        log.Info("I'm a simple log4net tutorial.");
        log.Warn("... better be careful ...");
        log.Error("ruh-roh: an error occurred");
        log.Fatal("OMG we're dooooooomed!");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    } while (true);
  }
```

When you get your logger it will use the new settings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer peer, i have tried it, but still, log level doesn't change.